# operation completion callback programming practice

Tags: c++, callback

Is adding a callback parameter for the case when operation completes (also fails) a good programming practice? Example:

```
template <typename F>
void load(::std::string const& path, F&& f)
{
  // after a long load
  ::std::invoke(f, path);
}
```

Here, `f` might be invoked in the context of another thread. My question comes from pondering whether it would be worthwhile to have one-fire signal/slot pairs in a program. That is, a slot, that would be called only once. Otherwise, we might need to connect, then disconnect a signal, which could be considered tedious. The rationale is, that, with a return value, such as a bool value, we need to wait for the result, whereas, with a callback, we don't need to.

Comment: The syntax seems odd to me. What's F supposed to be? Why not `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: any invokable object, as `::std::invoke` shows

Comment: I think using the observer pattern would be better for maintainability.

Comment: You may look at `std::future`. even if we don't have `then` yet.

Comment: @Jarod42 Great :) But the callback seems a little simpler to me

Comment: Hard to tell if this is too broad or too opinion based. Might this be better suited for Programmers?

Comment: I read a lot of questions regarding good programming practices on SO. Asked some others myself.

Comment: @Barry when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Wasn't suggesting cross-posting. Was suggesting moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bad practice in general. It's a fairly fundamental piece of asynchronous programming, as can be seen in [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Boost.Asio uses almost that same syntax for all of its callback functions, except that it's C++03 and so it can't use `invoke`. An example is [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html), where the caller tells Asio to read from a socket and then call the callback function when finished, with the requirement (enforced via templates) that the callback function take in an `error_code` as an argument that will be populated appropriately.